# OnCollisionEnter with polygon collider 2d and input.getmousebutton

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a tree in my game which has a polygon collider.  The player also has a polygon collider, with rigidbody 2d. If my player touches the tree and the left mouse button is pressed, then I want to add +1 to wood stock. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollisions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnCollisionStay (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.name == "Tree" && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("WOOD");
        }
    }
}
```

For now I have a debug just to check that it's working - it isn`t.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you're using 3D equivalent of CollisionStay. For 2D physics you have to take advantage of `void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)` - with `2D` at the end of function signature.